# Open a csproj and not the entire solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, solution, csproj

I am working on a solution that contains 30 cs projects. I am focusing on only 1 project so I preferred to open only this specific project.
Once opening this specific project, it loads the entire solution wiht all the others 29 projects.
Is there a way to open only this specific csproj?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you can't. That's probably because projects included in a solution always have some sort of connection. Mostly solution-internal references. Loading just one could cause incompatibilities or build issues. You can unload projects, though (right click on the node in the Solution Explorer and then 'Unload').

Comment: I worked only with vs 2010 . if the specific project is having dependencies with rest of the projects in solution then you will face a lot of issue. If not then there will be a project file separately you can open it directly.

Comment: Create a new empty solution and add the existing project, this should do the trick :-)

Comment: Maybe it is because dependencies as you both mentioned

Comment: I use a VS extension called Funnel (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5396fa4a-d638-471b-ac3d-671ccd2ea369) that really helps me with this. You can select the projects you want to load, and tell it to load all dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following structure can be used to get the desired behaviour:

- Create a new Visual Studio solution
- Delete the created default project
- Add an existing project to the solution
- Set the project as startup project (for re-build etc...)

You are now ready to go

Comment: Thank you, this is a workaround that I am familiar with. I was wondering if there is a solution such as setting a preference in VS or opening the project in a such way that it will be loaded without all the others projects

Comment: not that i'm aware of. Note that the .sln file is a simple file that holds all links to the .csproj files and some compile settings

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in minutes and it's quite simple. Each sln file contains a number of projects that are written in this form :

**Project(...) = "name.of.the.project", "{unique identifier of the project}"**

and below that are the configurations for that project.

So you can write a javascript file to copy your original sln into each project folder found in that sln. After that iterate through each project folder and for each sln remove other projects. The javascript file can be runned using a .bat or cmd.

In this way you can assure that each project of your solution has inside his folder a new solution that contains that project.

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution at work which has hundreds of projects. 
So what we have done is have a Main.sln which contains everything. Then were have broken up the rest of the projects into different smaller solutions where they are grouped by relevance.

ie. All the database projects are in one solution, UI projects in another etc.